# Using input dialog boxes in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a function that is something like this:

```
function [ c ] = input_args(m)

for i = 1 : m+1

    c{i} = inputdlg('Enter next m value');

end

end
```

Now I'd like to change this so that the instruction to the user at the i'th stage of the for loop says something like "Enter the i'th m value", where `i` is the changing index in the for loop. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A string is a array of characters, so you can concatenate them like any other array. You need to use `num2str` to convert a number into a printable character.

```
inputdlg(['Enter the ' num2str(i) 'th m value']);
```

A more general solution would be to use [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) to format your string; to do the same thing with sprintf you would use:

```
inputdlg(sprintf('Enter the %dth m value', i));
```

which you might find more readable (and allows you to use standard fprintf formatting options).